# How do I check if a user name already exists in Database

Tags: c#, database

I've seen this question asked a couple times but I couldn't find a good answer. I've been stuck for hours on this.

Basically I have usernames saved in a database and when a new user registers I want to check if his username is available - and if it is available add him to the database. And they register through a textbox called FName. The table is called Users.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FName FROM Users WHERE FName =  ????? usernames????? ", con);

con.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) 
{
     Console.WriteLine(reader["text"].ToString());
}
```

How can I fix this code?

Comment: Use parameters on the command to send the name you want to check for, and change that reader loop to use `FName` instead of `text`.

Comment: Seems like a shame to reinvent the wheel when .NET already has this exact functionality built into `WebMatrix` and `membership providers`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"SELECT FName FROM Users WHERE FName = @paramUsername"
```

and then you insert the parameter into the cmd like so:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("paramUsername", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["paramUsername"].Value = "Theusernameyouarelookingfor";
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :) but...

cmd.Parameters["paramUsername"].Value = "Theusernameyouarelookingfor"

what exactly do I write there? I am looking for every possible name. Not a psecific one...

Comment: Well, you do know what name the user is trying to register. You only need to query the database to see if the name is already taken. The query above returns the username if it is already in the database, and nothing if it is not. So in other words, if you get 0 results, you are good to go with the requested username. I hope it got a bit clearer.

Comment: it's clearer but how do i query the database? (i'm pretty new to programming and if you know where I can read about this stuff that would help)

Comment: The code doesn't work? I'm not sure if you can use the reader as a dictionary or not, but I usually write it as `reader.GetString(0)`. If this is not the problem, what error message do you get, or what is the problem?

Comment: nothing happens when i click login. I either want to say succesfully logged in or user does not exist. Where would I write that??

Comment: Well, if it's some kind of Windows user interface, I would suppose you set a label's text to something appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

string validationQuery = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE FName = @name";
SqlCommand validationCommand = new SqlCommand(validationQuery, connection);
validationCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUserSelected;

connection.Open();

SqlDataReader validationReader = validationCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

if (!validationReader.Read())
{
    string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Users (FName) VALUES (@name)";
    SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUserSelected;

    connection.Open();

    insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    insertCommand.Dispose();

    connection.Close();
}
else
{
    //Uh oh, username already taken
}

validationReader.Close();

validationCommand.Dispose();
```

Things to note:

- Use **parameters**, avoid concatenating strings because it's a security vulnerability
- Always `Close` and `Dispose` your ADO objects

Comment: Where do I import SqlDbType, loginUserSelected, CommandBehavior from??
***I imported SqlDbType and CommandBehavior but what do I do with loginUserSelected??

Comment: `loginUserSelected` comes from your interface, it's the string that the user submitted.

Comment: the name loginUserSelected does not exist in the current context

Comment: You have this data coming from an interface (WebForms, WinForms, MVC, whatever), right? This interface has a field where the user inputs his username, right? Add a line like `string loginUserSelected = myTextbox.Text;`. Got it?

Comment: got it but now there is another problem with your code. When I enter the username and press login I get an error at this point - connection.open(); 

the connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

Comment: and then when i delete connection.open() from the code the error says: connection needs to be open. Current connection is closed

Comment: @user2456977 Glad to  help. Don't forget to upvote and mark the answer that most helped you (it's the way this site goes, you know)